# Spring security expression based access control - referencing beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm attempting to use expression based access control in Spring security by referencing a bean method in my web security expression. So for example I have something like this

```
@Component
public class AuthorizationChecker {
    public boolean check(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then security configure method like this

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().anonymous().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**")
            .access("@authorizationChecker(authentication, request)").and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
}
```

However when starting the Spring Boot application I get Parsing exception. Digging through the Spring code I can see it fails parsing with the following message

> EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lparen(()'

Any ideas? As far as I can see it matches the syntax given in the Spring Security documentation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7/servlet/authorization/expression-based.html#el-access-web-beans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this, note the explicit call of the `check` method:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**")
            .access("@authorizationChecker.check(authentication, request)")
        .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
}
```

Comment: Gahhh how did I not spot that. Been staring at that for hours, thank you